# Extract array from file using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

X=np.array([[1, 2, 4]]).T
print(X)
y=np.array([1, 4, 16])
print(y)
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2),  
LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False))
model.fit(X,y)
X_predict = np.array([[3]])
print(model.predict(X_predict))
```

Plese, i'd like to extract X and y from a file like this:

```
x | y
1 | 1
2 | 4
4 | 16
```

(This is an example. My file contains more than 100 ligne).
What method i have to use ?
Kind regards.

Comment: is y = x**2 in all cases ?

Comment: No. my goal is to determine the proper degree of the polynomial by calculating each time the error rate between the value given on column y and the value predicted by the generated model.  I need now just how can i read from the file

Comment: What is the extension of the file ?

Comment: the extension of the file is .txt

Comment: Should `X=np.array([[1, 2, 4]]).T` be `X=np.array([1, 2, 4]).T` ?

Comment: i can have different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        b = line.split("|")
        x,y = b
```

In this code x is the integer before `|` and y is integer after `|`.

So total code would be:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
X_arr = []
Y_arr = []
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        b = line.split("|")
        x,y = b
        X_arr.append(int(x))
        Y_arr.append(int(y))


X=np.array([X_arr]).T
print(X)
y=np.array(Y_arr)
print(y)
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2),  
LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False))
model.fit(X,y)
X_predict = np.array([[3]])
print(model.predict(X_predict))
```

Comment: Please, can i do that with open('https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7hrpq6go60wxk7/input.txt?dl=0') as fp:     using  http://jupyter.org/try  ?

Comment: You will have to download it

Comment: And then download python and then run it

Comment: Done. i have to use with open('C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\input.txt') as fp:  ? is it correct ?

Comment: C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\input.txt   works fine.  But i a have these errors  https://imgur.com/a/UrCnfCq   https://imgur.com/a/iZtjcGb

Comment: @user1543915 remove the first line in text file

Comment: YES :) thnaks a lot :)